# SQL query: Get average, and average of everything higher than some value, in same query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a column of numbers in a MySQL database, along with a timestamp column and other stuff. I want to know the average of all of the values within a set parameter (say, within the last week), and I also want the average of all of the values that are >= X during that same timeframe. So, if my X is 10, and my values are:
`0 0 10 15 20`, then I want `avg = 9` and `avg2 = 15`. One way I can do this is run two separate queries, with and without `WHERE val >= 10`, but I'd like to do it in just one query, if possible. Is there a way of doing this? I've looked at using a CASE, but I can't get the syntax right. Below is the query that I tried:

`SELECT AVG(watts), AVG(CASE watts WHEN watts >= 10 THEN watts END CASE) FROM power WHERE meterID = 100 AND time >= '2010-07-29 00:00:00'`

**Edit:** This is what I ended up with.

```
SELECT AVG(watts) AS avg1,
AVG(IF (watts >= 10, watts, NULL)) AS avg2
FROM power
WHERE meterID = 100 AND time >= '2010-07-30 00:00:00'
```

Comment: In your description, you said values >= X, but your query shows `watts > 10` - shouldn't it be `watts >= 10`?

Comment: D'oh. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: Ah, nice adjustment; very clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
   AVG(watts),
   SUM(IF(watts>10,watts,0))/SUM(IF(watts>10,1,0))
FROM FOO
WHERE
   meterID   = 100 and
   time      >= '2010-07-29 00:00:00'
```

**Version 2**

```
SELECT
 AVG(watts),
 IF(SUM(IF(watts>10,1,0))=0,NULL,SUM(IF(watts>10,watts,0))/SUM(IF(watts>10,1,0)))
FROM FOO
WHERE
   meterID   = 100 and
   time      >= '2010-07-29 00:00:00'
```

Comment: What if no records have watts>10?

Answer (score 2):

This should work better:

```
SELECT AVG(watts) AS average_watts,
    AVG(CASE WHEN watts > 10 THEN watts END CASE) AS average_watts_floored
FROM MyTable
WHERE meterID = 100 AND time >= '2010-07-29 00:00:00'
```

You need a `FROM` clause if you have a `WHERE` clause.  Actually, you need a `FROM` clause if you're calculating any kind of `AVG()` too.

In the `CASE`, you should leave out the first column name if you're going to have expressions instead of literal values.  Refer to [syntax documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case).

I recommend using column aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries might be better.  You'll only hit the DB once.

```
SELECT AVG(watts), 
    (SELECT AVG(watts) 
     WHERE meterID = 100 AND time >= '2010-07-29 00:00:00' and watts > 10) as AVG2
WHERE meterID = 100 AND time >= '2010-07-29 00:00:00';
```

Comment: you might be able to drop the "meterID = 100 AND time >= '2010-07-29 00:00:00' and" from the subquery, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(watts) AS average_watts,
    AVG(CASE WHEN watts > 10 THEN watts ELSE NULL END CASE) AS average_watts_floored
FROM MyTable
WHERE meterID = 100 AND time >= '2010-07-29 00:00:00'
```

The "ELSE NULL" excludes the values <= 10 from begint included in the average